# Windows keeps on asking boot device

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, boot

I bought a used HDD from a friend of mine from his old laptop. I popped the drive in my desktop all is going smooth. Already did a (quick) reformat of the said drive,restarted my computer and adjusted the boot order. Already installed some programs in it and ran for a couple of days without any issues.

All is well until the latest update of Windows forced my PC to restart. Upon hearing the beeping sound when my PC is restarting, past the MOBO logo, it keeps on asking for the boot device, again and again.

Here's what I've tried/trying to do:

1. Rearranged the boot order.
2. Removed the second hand drive.
3. Using the second hand drive, I accessed the cmd to run sfc /scannow and chkdsk (This one is weird because i have a Windows boot manager that belongs to the second hand drive but I have reformated it)
4. Currently downloading win10 image to boot from a flasdrive.

Currently i can't boot to Windows and when i tried to reset, it says that my boot drive(SSD) is locked.

Drives: 120GB OCZ Trion SSD, 1TB WD Blue, 500TB Toshiba Laptop Drive(Secondhand)

Answer (score 0):

you must use diskpart to get rid of boot partition on friends hard drive format will not get to that partition from diskpart erase all partitons then go to disk manager and create a new volume

Comment: I can't boot to Windows and when i tried to reset the OS(not the reset button), it says that my boot drive(SSD) is locked.

Any chance i could do that using CMD of a USB boot?

Comment: @Lyreem Boot to install media, hit Shift+F10 and type `diskpart`. From there, `lis dis` to list the disk, `sel dis X` where X is the disk number to select the disk, and then `clean` to clean the drive of everything.

Comment: @td512 Is there an option just to wipe the partition of the second hand drive? Maybe that is what is causing the error. I already have some files stored in that drive for my research paper.

Thanks for the reply.